# Keyboard messed up in both Windows and Ubuntu after updates

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 with Wubi to try it out on my Asus N82J notebook. Problem is that during the software updates after installation, the keyboard got messed. Like when I press "o" it appears "no", "b" reproduces "ba", stuff like that. I changed layouts many times and problem continues.

So I changed back to Windows to search on Internet what it could be and for my surprise, Windows is having the same issue. Other thing that I noticed is that Windows had the same clock time as Ubuntu.

Anyone knows what can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `/etc/default/keyboard`, and locate this:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

The line you may have to change is **`XKBLAYOUT=""`**.
Make sure that `XKBLAYOUT` is `"us"`.
Then run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

in the terminal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am just finishing a backup and will try this out. The problem is that I uninstalled Ubuntu, so I would have to install again as well. Other thing is that the keyboard still broken even when I enter on BIOS setup. Anyway, will try this soon.

Comment: Ok problem is that I cannot log on my user, cuz when I hit Enter a blank space is added too, like the "o" that adds a "n". And as guest I can't use sudo, and also don't know where to find the etc directory.

Comment: Managed to do all that with an external usb keyboard, that worked perfectly, but did not solve my notebook keyboard problem.